# Count number of occurrences per hour between two dates SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've created a temp table `#MB` that has a record ID (119 rows), start and end date (partial screenshot of the list is below):

[image]

I'm trying to get a count of occurrences that happened each hour for each record ID during the start and end date (or number of occurrences each hour when `ID` was active between two dates).

I've used this code:

```
SELECT *  
FROM  
    (SELECT  
         ISNULL(CAST(part AS VARCHAR(5)), 'Total') AS part,
         COUNT(*) AS part_count
     FROM    
         (SELECT DATEPART([HOUR], [Start]) AS part
          FROM #MB) grp
     GROUP BY
         GROUPING SETS((part),())
    ) pre
PIVOT   
    (MAX(part_count) 
         FOR part IN ([0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8],
                      [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16],
                      [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], Total)
    ) pvt;
```

but it counts only records based on the start date (don't count each hour between two dates) and I stuck on how to generate occurrences per hour for each ID between two dates that I can later use to pre-aggregate and pivot.

[image]

Comment: Generate or load a table with one row per hour.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @HABO!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to generate the list of rows for each hour

here i am using a recursive cte query to do it

```
; with MB as
(
    select  ID, [Start], [End], [Date] = [Start]
    from    #MB

    union all

    select  ID, [Start], [End], [Date] = dateadd(hour, 1, convert(date, c.[Date]))
    from    MB c
    where   dateadd(hour, 1, c.[Date])  < [End]
)
select  *
from    MB
```

so in your pivot query , just change to this

```
; with MB as
(
    select  ID, [Start], [End], [Date] = [Start]
    from    #MB

    union all

    select  ID, [Start], [End], [Date] = DATEADD(HH,DATEPART(HH,[Start]),CAST(CAST([Start] AS DATE) AS DATETIME))
    from    MB c
    where   dateadd(hour, 1, c.[Date])  < [End]
)
SELECT  *  
FROM    (
            SELECT  ISNULL(CAST(part AS VARCHAR(5)), 'Total')   AS part,
                    COUNT(*)            AS part_count
            FROM    (
                        SELECT  DATEPART([HOUR], [Date]) AS part
                        FROM    MB   -- changed to the cte
                    ) grp
            GROUP BY
                    GROUPING SETS((part),())
        ) pre
PIVOT   (MAX(part_count) FOR part IN (
            [0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],
            [9],[10],[11],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],
            [17],[18],[19],[20],[21],[22],[23], Total)) pvt;
```

Comment: Thanks Squirrel. But I'm getting the error message: Invalid object name 'cte' as I do not have cte table... Could you explain how a recursive cte query works?

Comment: I managed to run the code after changing rcte to MBcte in 3 places (altered your code above a bit), though still need to figure out how it works :-)

Comment: Fixed the query.  You need to read up recursive CTE understand how it works

Comment: I found one issue with the code, for example: if the Start time is bigger than the End time than the last hour will be missed, like with ID 79718685. To solve this issue I've slightly changed the code in the recursive CTE part to [Date] = DATEADD(HH,DATEPART(HH,[Start]),CAST(CAST([Start] AS DATE) AS DATETIME)). Now it works like a charm :-)